# How to test for existence of a script-scoped variable in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to test for the existence of a script-scoped variable in PowerShell?

I've been using the [PowerShell Community Extensions (PSCX)](http://pscx.codeplex.com/) but I've noticed that if you import the module while `Set-PSDebug -Strict` is set, an error is produced:

```
The variable '$SCRIPT:helpCache' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
At C:\Users\...\Modules\Pscx\Modules\GetHelp\Pscx.GetHelp.psm1:5 char:24
```

While investigating how I might fix this, I found this piece of code in Pscx.GetHelp.psm1:

```
#requires -version 2.0

param([string[]]$PreCacheList)

if ((!$SCRIPT:helpCache) -or $RefreshCache) {
    $SCRIPT:helpCache = @{}
}
```

This is pretty straight forward code; if the cache doesn't exist or needs to be refreshed, create a new, empty cache. The problem is that calling `$SCRIPT:helpCache` while `Set-PSDebug -Strict` is in force casues the error because the variable hasn't been defined yet.

Ideally, we could use a `Test-Variable` cmdlet but such a thing doesn't exist! I thought about looking in the `variable:` provider but I don't know how to determine the scope of a variable.

So my question is: how can I test for the existence of a variable while `Set-PSDebug -Strict` is in force, without causing an error?

Comment: If you're on PowerShell 2.0, I would recommend using `Set-StrictMode -version 2.0` as it will catch additional potential issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `test-path variable:SCRIPT:helpCache`

```
if (!(test-path variable:script:helpCache)) {
  $script:helpCache = @{}
}
```

This works for me without problems.
Checked using this code:

```
@'
Set-PsDebug -strict
write-host (test-path variable:script:helpCache)
$script:helpCache = "this is test"
write-host (test-path variable:script:helpCache) and value is $script:helpCache
'@ | set-content stricttest.ps1

.\stricttest.ps1
```

Comment: I added an example that really works for me. If you have any problems, I need to know what the problems are ;)

Comment: This is probably the best way. The trick with [h]elpCache is faster (just a little bit) but it is hacky. Also, Test-Path way is much better when a variable’s name is a variable itself, i.e. Test-Path variable:script:$name

Comment: FWIW, using `test-path variable:` is the approach we usually take in PSCX.  I'll take a look at this issue later tonight.

Comment: @stej That does not work with the `$env:OS` variable. How do I test if `$env:OS` is defined ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this trick:

```
Get-Variable [h]elpCache -Scope Script
```

It should not throw or emit any errors because we use a wildcard `[h]elpCache`. On the other hand this kind of a wildcard is a literal name de facto.

Comment: Yes, this way is hacky. @stej proposes a better solution. Still, the trick with fake wildcard is useful in many cases, e.g. for Get-Process (there is no Test-Path alternative for processes).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Get-Variable` with the `-Scope` parameter. This cmdlet will (by default at least) not return only the variable's value but a `PSVariable` object and will throw an exception if the variable isn't found:

```
Get-Variable foo -Scope script
```

Comment: @Johannes Thanks for the answer. It's the exception that's thrown by `Get-Variable` that I'm trying to avoid though. I can do that with `try/catch` obviously, but I'd like to know if there's a more readable way that doesn't splurge red text into my output window. :)

Comment: *Get-Variable -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue* should do the trick. You can check the result of the command call. N.B. The error is still added to the $Error list, unfortunately.

Comment: @Roman Kuzmin The `-ErrorAction` trick didn't help. Shame, because that seems like a good solution.